# Do embedded GeoJSON styles work with Mapbox GL?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to utilize the built-in `properties` attribute of a GeoJSON data source to automatically style a Mapbox GL map without having to pre-specify a style?

I have a use case where I dynamically load in GeoJSON `LineString` data that needs to be a particular color and it already has style data built in:

`{"properties": {"color": "#ffff33"...`

Right now, I have a rather inelegant setup where the relevant color is parsed out, translated into a style, and added to the map upon every load:

```
    $scope.patternPropToStyle = function(props) {
      var id = 'pattern' + props.pid;
      var style = {
        "id": id,
        "type": "line",
        "source": id,
        "render": {
          "$type": "LineString",
          "line-join": "round",
          "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
          "line-color": props.color,
          "line-width": 8
        }
      }
      $scope._mapStyle.layers.push(style);
      $scope._map.setStyle($scope._mapStyle);
    }
```

I feel like there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no - [simplestyle-spec](https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec) isn't supported in Mapbox GL. Currently the GeoJSON support is still very primitive, given that the focus was initially on vector tiles. simplestyle-spec support is certainly in the plans.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I'm trying to convert a webapp that makes heavy use of GeoJSON to Mapbox GL, so I'll see what I can hack together in the mean time. :)